# In webapi asp.net I am getting following error.,response status code does not indicate success 404 (not found)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am getting following error when calling get method from web API.
This is my controller class.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/AnnouncementController")]
public class AnnouncementController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    [Route("{code}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<EAnnouncement> Get(string code)
    {
        return AnnouncementC.getdata(code);
    }
    ...
}
```

This is my configuartion:

```
{
     public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
     {
         // Web API routes
         config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
     }
}

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{    
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

Here I am calling get method.But do not getting error. Please help me

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Jcode = (string)(Session["JCode"]);

    GridView2.DataSource = addressBookGrid_GetData(Jcode);
    GridView2.DataBind();
}

public IQueryable<EAnnouncement> addressBookGrid_GetData(string code)
{
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1146");
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

     HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/AnnouncementController").Result;
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

     List<EAnnouncement> addressBooks = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<EAnnouncement>>().Result;

     return addressBooks.AsQueryable();    
 }
```

Comment: paste the code which is calling the api.

Comment: It is added above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove controller name while calling the service

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Announcement")]

 HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Announcement").Result;
```

your api methord is expecting one parameter pass the parameter like

```
 client.GetAsync("api/Announcement/1").Result;
```

`[Route("api/Announcement/{code}")]` decorate with this attribute on the top of your action methord

Comment: you are not passing the parameter to the api

Comment: with pleasure if it helps you accept it as the answer@Hooriya